# Atlantean Form of Government

Tags: government, form-of-government

In Critias, Plato says that the 10 Atlantean kings held a meeting every other 5 or 6th year alternately. In the meeting they would consult their common interests, inquire if anyone had transgressed and if anyone had dedicate their sentence together. The kings had complete control over their citizens and most over their law (they had to follow the laws Poseidon had inscribed on the pillar).

What kind of government would this be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your description, there are ten kingdoms with ten kings which would mean ten monarchies<sup>1</sup>

What the text describes is more akin to international politics, which each king being the head of state of a different country, and the reunion could be likened to an international summit or even to an organization similar to the NU (although it seems that it would lack the permanent institutions that the ONU does have).

---

<sup>1</sup>Now, these monarchies could be of several types (elective, hereditary, absolute, "parliamentary", etc.)

Comment: But if I want to refer to it as one entity, would I refer to it as a decarchy?

Comment: Did they share responsabilities? If a king decided to levy a tax on their subjects, could the others "outvote" him? If a subject decided that a king was unfair, could he appeal to the other kings? Unless they worked that way, it reads af different countries just having a meeting of heads of state, or an international alliance.

Comment: As one unit, it is an alliance, or federation. The kings remember are god-kings. Sons of Possiedon. There is no real form of government with a god a absolute ruler.

Comment: So just an alliance then, right? Thanks for your help!